# SIGTERM not received by java process using 'docker stop' and the official java image

Tags: java, docker, dropwizard, dockerfile

I am running a dropwizard Java application in a Docker container using the image `java:7u79` based on `debian/jessie`.

My Java application handles the `SIGTERM` signal to shutdown gracefully. The `SIGTERM` handling works perfect when I run the application without Docker.

When I run it in a Docker container the `SIGTERM` does not reach the Java application when I issue a `docker stop` command. It kills the process abruptly after 10 seconds.

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM java:7u79

COPY dropwizard-example-1.0.0.jar /opt/dropwizard/
COPY example.keystore /opt/dropwizard/
COPY example.yml /opt/dropwizard/

WORKDIR /opt/dropwizard

RUN java -jar dropwizard-example-1.0.0.jar db migrate /opt/dropwizard/example.yml

CMD java -jar dropwizard-example-1.0.0.jar server /opt/dropwizard/example.yml

EXPOSE 8080 8081
```

What is wrong with this `Dockerfile`? Is there any other way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Do you really want to run your DB-migration during docker build (instead of during runtime)?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Assuming you launch a Java service by defining the following in your `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD java -jar ...
```

When you now enter the container and list the processes e.g. by `docker exec -it <containerName> ps AHf` (I did not try that with the `java` but with the `ubuntu` image) you see that your Java process is not the root process (not the process with PID 1) but a child process of a `/bin/sh` process:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 18:27 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c java -jar ...
root         8     1  0 18:27 ?        00:00:00   java -jar ...
```

So basically you have a Linux shell that is the main process with PID 1 which has a child process (Java) with PID 8.

To get signal handling working properly you should avoid those shell parent process. That can be done by using the builtin shell command `exec`. That will make the child process taking over the parent process. So at the end the former parent process does not exist any more. And the child process becomes the process with the PID 1. Try the following in your `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD exec java -jar ...
```

The process listing then should show something like:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 18:30 ?        00:00:00 java -jar ...
```

Now you only have that one process with PID 1. Generally a good practice is to have docker containers only contain one process - the one with PID 1 (or if you really need more processes then you should use e.g. [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/) as PID 1 which itself takes care of signal handling for its child processes).

With that setup the `SIGTERM` will be treated directly by the Java process. There is no shell process any more in between which could break signal handling.

**EDIT**:

The same `exec` effect could be achieved by using a different `CMD` syntax that does it implicitly (thanks to [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1452016/andy) for his comment):

```
CMD ["java", "-jar", "..."]
```

Comment: That's a good answer, but it might be even better if they used `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` with the _exec_ format, for example `ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","..."]` https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: `CMD ["java", "-jar", ...]` was not working with `ENV` variables, but `CMD exec java -jar` solved my problem :)

Comment: I had the same problem, this answer helps a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

@h3nrik answer is right but sometimes you really need to use a script for setup the launch. Just use the exec command to do the trick in most of the cases:

```
#!/bin/sh

#--- Preparations

exec java -jar ...
```

See this wonderful [blog post](http://veithen.github.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html)