# How to pass flags to java process in Docker contatiner built by Cloud Native Buildpacks (CNB)

Tags: spring-boot, docker, buildpack

Normally when I create Docker image I do something like this:

```
FROM openjdk:15-jdk-slim

ARG version=undefined
LABEL version=${version}

WORKDIR /
COPY build/libs/v2t-api-$version.jar /v2t-api.jar

USER nobody

VOLUME ["/tmp"]

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "exec java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar v2t-api.jar"]
```

So, when I start my container in for example kubernetes I can set JAVA_OPTS which defines how many memory is available for heap or how many CPUs are actually there.

Packaging OCI Images using built-in [gradle plugin from Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image) looks interesting, but I can't find how to do something similar in buildpacks - I would like to set some flags to java process, so how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the Paketo.io docs](https://paketo.io/docs/buildpacks/configuration/#environment-variables) there are 2 kinds of environment variables one could pass to the Paketo build:

1. [Build-time Environment Variables](https://paketo.io/docs/buildpacks/configuration/#build-time-environment-variables)
2. [Runtime Environment Variables](https://paketo.io/docs/buildpacks/configuration/#runtime-environment-variables)

If I understand your question correctly you're looking for a way to configure Runtime Environment variables (2.). In order to do that you need to pass environment variables to the container running your app (which was build by CNB/Paketo before) e.g. by using the `--env` flag. As the docs state

> Users may configure runtime features of the app image by setting
> environment variables in the app container. The names of variables
> accepted by buildpack-provided runtime components [..] are prefixed with BPL_ or have well-known
> conventional meanings outside of Paketo (e.g JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS).

So for example if you build an container image called `v2t-api:latest`, then you can run your container with:

```
docker run --env "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m" v2t-api:latest
```

I can advice you to switch from `JAVA_OPTS` to `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`, because your application won't receive the sigterm in case of a graceful shutdown & your app wouldn't be shutdown correctly (see [this so answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58355963/4964553)).

Comment: How didn't I know about `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`?.. Thanks!

Comment: I have to admit I didn't knew it either - but learned about it trying to answer your questions :)