# Setting Java env variables in docker-compose

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I want to pass couple of variables to my springboot application as environment variables.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev         --> spring profile
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED      --> needed for java 17
```

I managed to supply the first one using

```
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
```

But tried different options for second. none worked.

```
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
      - --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
      - "--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"

    environment: JAVA_OPTS >
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
      --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

    environment: JAVA_OPTS=-Dspring.profiles.active=dev=local --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

    environment: JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev=local --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: JAVA_OPTS must be passed to your ENTRY_POINT or CMD as part of the java command in order to work properly, but it causes other sort of issues. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53785577/passing-java-opts-to-spring-boot-application-through-docker-compose for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Finally, here is our real hero 'JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS'.

```
environment:
  - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
  - "JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS=--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
```

My docker-compose is happy :)

> | NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: --add-opens
> java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

> JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS is only picked up by the java launcher, so use it for
> options that you only want to apply (or only make sense for) the java
> startup command. This variable is also new on JDK 9+, and will be
> ignored by earlier JDK versions. Hence, it's useful when migrating
> from older versions to 9+.
>
> JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is picked up also by other java tools like jar and
> javac so it should be used for flags that you want to apply (and are
> valid) to all those java tools.
>
> [What is the difference between JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS when using Java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986487/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-java-options-and-java-tool-options-when-using)

JAVA_OPTS is **NOT AT ALL** an option.
ref: [Running java with JAVA_OPTS env variable has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011311/running-java-with-java-opts-env-variable-has-no-effect)